# Como é calculado a raridade das medalhas?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Como é calculado a raridade das medalhas ganhas de cada utilizador para mostrar no perfil do mesmo, vejam a imagem abaixo para perceberem o que falo. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que são as que menos gente tem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quanto mais raro significa que menos delas foram concedidas. Dentre as que você conquistou temos:

> **Ouro**
>   Copidesque 30 concedidas
>   Eleitorado 90 concedidas
>
> **Prata**
>   Incentivador 1  concedida
>   Arqueólogo 9 concedidas
>   Representante 82 concedidas
>
> **Bronze**
>   Revisor 93 concedidas
>   Disciplinado 96 concedidas
>   Anunciador 136 concedidas

Pode ver a lista completa aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/

Answer (score 9):

Para todas as medalhas, é só calcular `x / y`, onde:

- `x` é a quantidade de vezes que a medalha foi concedida;
- `y` é a quantidade total de medalhas de todos os tipos concedidas.

Você pode acumular o resultado em um mapa, onde a chave é o valor da divisão e o valor é uma estrutura que contém várias medalhas que possuem aquele resultado. Ao ordenar as chaves em ordem crescente, as primeiras chaves conterão as medalhas mais raras.